# comparing two numpy 2D arrays for similarity

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.x

I have 2D numpy `array1` that contains only `0` and `255` values

```
 ([[255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0, 255,   0, 255],
   [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [255,   0, 255,   0, 255]])
```

and an `array2` that is identical in size and shape as `array1` and also contains only `0` and `255` values

```
 ([[255,   0, 255,   0, 255],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
   [255,   0,   0,   0, 255],
   [  0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
   [255,   0, 255,   0,   0]])
```

How can I compare `array1` to `array2` to determine a similarity percentage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how would you define similarity for your arrays?

Comment: You could substract the arrays from each other and sum over the resulting array squared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you only have two possible values, I would propose this algorithm for similarity-checking:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0, 255,   0, 255],
   [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
   [255,   0, 255,   0, 255]])

B = np.array([[255,   0, 255,   0, 255],
   [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
   [255,   0,   0,   0, 255],
   [  0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
   [255,   0, 255,   0,   0]])

number_of_equal_elements = np.sum(A==B)
total_elements = np.multiply(*A.shape)
percentage = number_of_equal_elements/total_elements

print('total number of elements: \t\t{}'.format(total_elements))
print('number of identical elements: \t\t{}'.format(number_of_equal_elements))
print('number of different elements: \t\t{}'.format(total_elements-number_of_equal_elements))
print('percentage of identical elements: \t{:.2f}%'.format(percentage*100))
```

It counts equal elements and calculates the percentage of the equal elements to the total number of elements

Comment: Do you ever get:

__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Comment: @skrhee Hm weird, I have numpy `1.19.2`, which seems to be the newest release, but I get no error. I would be surprised if elementwise comparison was deprecated

Comment: I think I get the error when my arrays are of different sizes.  When I rewrite my code to loop through elementwise it seems to work fine. 

Thank you for your help and posts!