# Check array to find if they are the same

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to programming in Python. I had used Matlab extensively. I want to check if in a 2D array,any two arrays are same. I have points lets say (x,y,z) coordinates in the format

```
data=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]...[xn,yn,zn]].
```

I want to check if any point is equal to another point. And if there are any similar instance, i want to know how many are same and which two are same. The code i have in Python is something like

```
data = [[1,2,3],[3,1,8],[4,2,5],[1,2,3]]
s=0
for i in range(len(data)):
  a=data[i]
  for j in range(len(data)):
    while i != j:
        if data[j]==a:
            s=s+1
            c=i
            d=j

print(s)
print(c,d)
```

and i also dont want the answer that point N is equal to point N etc
I also have used

```
for j in range(i,len(R)):
```

but it also dont give the correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comparing two numpy 2D arrays for similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521531/comparing-two-numpy-2d-arrays-for-similarity)

Comment: Thanks, but got it working after a while.


print(x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This working well:

```
data =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[2,5,6],[0,9,1],[1,5,7],[2,5,4]]
st=[]
dic={}
while len(data)>1:
    d = data[0]
    data.remove(d)
    st=[]
    for dat in data:
        k=0
        for i in d:
            if i in dat:
                k=k+1
        if k>1:
            st.append(dat)
    if len(st)>0:
        dic[str(d)]=st
for key in dic.keys():
    print(key," : ", dic[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, found a workthrough myself

```
d=[[1,2,3],[3,5,4],[5,6,9],[0,2,1],[1,2,3]]
s=0
for i in range(len(d)):
   for j in range(i+1,len(d)):
       if d[i]==d[j]:
           s=s+1
           x=i
           y=j
print(s)
print(x,y)
```